# Avoid nested regexp_replace( ) for changing multiple char(s) in a string

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to replace multiple char(s) in a string using a simple query for Oracle 11g. Now I use:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(colName, 'a', 'x'), 'b', 'y' ) 'c', 'z') from myTable;
```

but I'm not very happy with it. What would be a more intuitive query that has the same output?

Comment: You don't need `regexp_replace` to do this, I think a normal replace should work, and I also don't see a nicer way of swapping letters.

Comment: Provided replaced character set and replacement set have no common characters you can use TRANSLATE https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm#i1501659

Comment: Are your characters as simple as `a,b,c` etc or do you actually have some regex to be replaced.?

Comment: @KaushikNayak simple characters (1 letter)

Comment: Then, I think normal `replace` or `translate` should be sufficient as mentioned in other comments.

Answer (score 2):

translate() searches the string in the first argument for characters in the second argument and replaces them with the characters found in the third argument that are in the same position as those in the second argument:

```
SQL> select translate('abc', 'abc', 'xyz')
     from dual;

TRA
---
xyz

SQL> select translate('tralalajustbecause','abc','xyz') from dual;

TRA
---
trxlxlxjustyezxuse
```

Comment: This is not as flexible as the nested regexp_replace(). I am looking for something that does: myTranslate('abc' , 'tralalajustbecause','xyz'); output: trxlxlxjustyezxuse

Comment: Well I followed your original example.  You should have included this example text, I wouldn't have posted this then.  sigh

Comment: Ok @Caius Jard, you talked me into undeleting it.  Let's see what happens, if anything. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The translate function will accomplish what you want:

```
select translate(colName, 'abc', 'xyz') from myTable;
```

Comment: What you can't see, is that this has been suggested before, in a deleted answer. Bizarrely the OP complained that it didn't do what he wanted, and the answerer deleted their suggestion, but the OP cited an example where it would have done exactly what he wanted.. I hence think translate is the right suggestion. He might also have solved his quandary by now :)

Comment: Oh interesting - yeah I saw the discussion in the comment but figured an executable example might be helpful.